# Trigger insert of data into table with result from another select query

Tags: sql, postgresql, user-defined-functions

Starting my first steps in SQL.

I'm trying to insert the last row of a timestamped table to another table.

I've written this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_analysis()
AFTER INSERT ON data
FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_to_analysis();
```

I've defined a function, which I know is wrong, but don't understand how to write it correctly. (the target table has these columns)

```
CREATE FUNCTION UPDATE_ANALYSIS() RETURNS TABLE
AS
$$ BEGIN
INSERT INTO ANALYSIS (TIME, CYCLE_NUMBER,CAT1,CAT2,CAT3)
SELECT (TIME, CYCLENO , I1 , I2 * 2 ,I3*3)
FROM DATA
ORDER BY TIME DESC
LIMIT 1;)

RETURN 
END;

$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you missing `VALUES` in your `INSERT`? Also, if you want to insert on `Analysis` whenever you insert on `data`. You can use `NEW` to gain access to the data you just inserted into `data`. (Instead of `SELECT` from the data) **Example**: NEW.I2 is the I2 value you just inserted into `data`

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a function for a trigger, it should return a trigger.

And it's for each row, so an insert from values is possible.

**Example**

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION FN_INSERT_TO_ANALYSIS() RETURNS TRIGGER
> AS $ins_analysis$ 
> BEGIN
>   INSERT INTO ANALYSIS (TIME, CYCLE_NUMBER, CAT1, CAT2, CAT3)
>   VALUES (NEW.TIME, NEW.CYCLENO, NEW.I1, NEW.I2 * 2 , NEW.I3 * 3);
> RETURN NEW;
> END $ins_analysis$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER trg_data_ins_analysis
> AFTER INSERT ON data
> FOR EACH ROW
> EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_insert_to_analysis();
> ```

> ```
> insert into data values (current_timestamp,1,1,1,1)
> ```

> ```
> select * from data
> ```

| time | cycleno | i1 | i2 | i3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-27 14:53:17.822649 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

> ```
> select * from ANALYSIS
> ```

| time | cycle_number | cat1 | cat2 | cat3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-27 14:53:17.822649 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f68fe1dd3895fcd413926f5dc7c1b33c)*

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing the same data you just inserted into `data`, you could simply refer to what you inserted instead of `SELECT`:ing, like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION UPDATE_ANALYSIS() RETURNS TABLE
AS
$$ BEGIN
INSERT INTO ANALYSIS (TIME, CYCLE_NUMBER,CAT1,CAT2,CAT3)
VALUES (NEW.TIME, NEW.CYCLENO , NEW.I1 , NEW.I2 * 2 ,NEW.I3 * 3);


RETURN NEW;
END;

$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```